# Properties of size function in a general Euclidean domain

Tags: ring-theory, factoring, euclidean-domain

In ring theory a given ring $R$ is called a Euclidean domain if there exists a function $\sigma:R -\{0\}\rightarrow \{0,1,2,3...\}   $ which satisfies the division algorithm i.e.
$ $
if $a,b \in R$ then there exists $q,r \in R$ such that  $b=aq+r$ and either $r=0$ or $\sigma(r)\lt \sigma(a) $

Now I want to ask if we can prove, using just this definition that an element of larger degree won't divide an element of smaller degree. In specific rings such as

(i) the integers

we can say$$\sigma(a)=|a|$$ $$\sigma(ab)=\sigma(a)\sigma(b)$$

ii) polynomials

where$$\sigma(f(x))=deg(f(x))$$$$\sigma(ab)=\sigma(a)+\sigma(b)$$
So in both the above cases the size of product of two elements will always be greater than or equal to the size of individual elements and hence the larger element can never divide the smaller element. But is this true in general for all Euclidean domains ? And how will we prove that

Comment: Generally it's only true if we choose an equivalent minimal Euclidean function (which can always be done - see the links)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Can't find the link ?

Comment: The dupe links are prepended to your question.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for the explanation. So does that mean an element which is larger than a given element with respect to a given Euclidean function will be smaller than the same element for another Euclidean function ?